# Make TIFF files transparent in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to make my scanned and georeferenced TIFF file translucent so I can see the layers underneath, however when I do so using the global opacity tool, it becomes pixelated, as shown in the image. How do I fix this?

[image: Tiff file becomes pixelated]

Comment: Try it with different blending modes.

Comment: like @csk lined out: use blending modes->Multiply for that